# Need to select all checkboxes and dynamically add specific event handler to each

Tags: jquery

Given the following repeated markup in a page:

```
<div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
     <div id="div1" >
          //stuff to toggle
     </div>
</div>
<div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" />
     <div id="div2" >
          //stuff to toggle
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I get all checkboxes and then dynamically add toggle to the associated div in an event handler for each checkbox?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('input:checkbox').each(
          function() {
               $(this).bind('click", function() {
                    //Attach toggle() to associate DIV
                    //$('#div1').toggle();
               });
          });
});
```

Is there a simple way to do this without resorting to either parsing or assuming an ordered list of IDs?

Answer (score 3):

- Use the `change` event, since that's really what you care about
- Use `.live()` so you only bind 1 listener, rather than 1 per checkbox
- Use DOM traversal to find the `<div>`

  ```
  $(function ()
  {
      $('input:checkbox').live('change', function ()
      {
          $(this).next().toggle();
      });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `each()` or `bind()`:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function (event) {
  //... using $(this)
});
```

Comment: You also don't need the `.bind('click', ...)` when `.click(...)` will do.